# Help selecting a microcontroler

Tags: wifi, hardware, microcontrollers, bluetooth-low-energy, power-consumption

I need you help, currently I`m searching for a microcontroller

1. That supports ultra power mode.
2. Has bluettoth support.
3. Can be waked up by a wireless interruption.
4. The microcontroller must be powered up by a battery as long as possible.
5. Also I want to find the cheapest version.

The microcontroller will be used in next scenary:

- It will stay in the low power mode, untill someone will send a
  request to uc from phone ( as the request can be made from anywhere, internet will be used) the uc will wake up and will read from a
  external pin a value, and will send back to server the response after
  this it will go back in low power mode.

I am pretty bad when it`s about electronic so your advices will help me a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: What’s the value to be read? On/off? An analog voltage? A digital signal (e.g. a query over SPI or I2C)? How often does it change? What kind of latency do you need? How long is “as long as possible”? Hours? Days? Months? Years? What is the intended size of the device?

Comment: First you need to clarify, what is "ultra power mode". Is it "Ultra low power consumption" then will the demand "send a request to uc from phone" not work. The uc cant listen to internet and be "Ultra low power" at the same time, listen to internet = High power consumption.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think all your requirements, as stated, are compatible. “Ultra low power running on battery as long as possible” and “connected to WiFi waiting for a request from a remote device on the Internet” are notably not things that are usually possible.

I see two options:

- Reverse the logic: the microcontroller sleeps as much as possible, but is set to wake up on a trigger on the pin changing state. Then it sends the data to a server over WiFi. Clients connect to that server to retrieve the last state.

This works if the state you are reading is just on/off and it doesn’t change too often.

Alternatively, if it’s something different from on/off, the controller may just wake up at regular intervals, read the current value, send to server, go back to sleep.

- Or use low-power technologies such as BLE, or probably better, Zigbee. This will require some form of gateway, but you can run a device advertising BLE waiting for connections for months if not years, and with Zigbee it could be even longer (and range is usually better).

We do lack quite a few details on what exactly you are trying to achieve so it’s difficult to say which option would be better in your case (or a modified version of one of those, or something altogether different).

Comment: " Reverse the logic: the microcontroller sleeps as much as possible, but is set to wake up on a trigger on the pin changing state. Then it sends the data to a server over WiFi. Clients connect to that server to retrieve the last state". 
  
- This option is fitting my requirements.